# Ifelse is returning wrong results

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Here is my code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

day <- c("20", "01")
my <- ifelse(is.na(day), NA, "042020")
value <- c(34, 23)
X <- ifelse(is.na(day), NA, paste(day, my, sep = ""))
Y <- ifelse(is.na(dmy), NA, rep("30042020"))
Z <- c("01082020", "01072020")
data <- data.frame(X, Y, Z, value)
data$X <- lubridate::dmy(X)
data$Y <- lubridate::dmy(Y)
data$Z <- lubridate::dmy(Z)
data
```

And this is my data:

```
           X          Y          Z value
1 2020-04-20 2020-04-30 2020-08-01    34
2 2020-04-01 2020-04-30 2020-07-01    23
```

I have three time variables. I want to create a new variable using two conditions:

- If `Z > Y`, `Y > X` and `Z` and `X` are not a `NA`, then replace value with the letter "`A`"
- If `X = 1st April` and `Z > Y`, and `Z` is not a NA, then replace value with the letter "`B`".

I am expecting a new variable called `adjValue` where the first row should be `A` and the second row should be `B`.

This is what I wrote,

```
data %>% mutate(adjValue = ifelse(Z > Y & Y > X & !is.na(Z) & !is.na(X), "A", ifelse(
  X == ymd(20200401) &  (Z > Y) & !is.na(Z), "B", value)))

           X          Y          Z value adjValue
1 2020-04-20 2020-04-30 2020-08-01    34        A
2 2020-04-01 2020-04-30 2020-07-01    23        A
```

As one can see, the `adjValue` second row is showing `A` instead of my expected `B`. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Your second row also matches the first condition and this is assigned "A", it doesn't matter that it also matches the condition for "B". If you switched the order of your `ifelse` statement it would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
#Your input
day <- c("20", "01")
my <- ifelse(is.na(day), NA, "042020")
value <- c(34, 23)
X <- ifelse(is.na(day), NA, paste(day, my, sep = ""))
Y <- ifelse(is.na(dmy), NA, rep("30042020"))
Z <- c("01082020", "01072020")
data <- data.frame(X, Y, Z, value)
data$X <- lubridate::dmy(X)
data$Y <- lubridate::dmy(Y)
data$Z <- lubridate::dmy(Z)
data
#Conditions
cond1 <- (data$Z > data$Y) & (data$Y>data$X) & !is.na(data$Z) & !is.na(data$X)
cond2 <- format(data$X,'%d-%m')=='01-04' & (data$Z>data$Y) & !is.na(data$Z)
#Assign valus
data$adjvalue<-NA
data$adjvalue[cond1]<-'A'
data$adjvalue[cond2]<-'B'

           X          Y          Z value adjvalue
1 2020-04-20 2020-04-30 2020-08-01    34        A
2 2020-04-01 2020-04-30 2020-07-01    23        B
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the second case (the one which you want to annotate as `B`) is a *subset* of your first case (the one falling under `A`). Take the second row for example, which you want to yield `B`. It's true that `Z > Y`, that `Y > X`, and that `Z` and `X` are not `NA`. As such, the first `ifelse` will return `A`. The second `ifelse` is only evaluated if the condition is false.

To make your code work, you simply need to check the conditions for `B` *before* those for `A`.

```
data %>% mutate(adjValue = ifelse(X == ymd(20200401) & (Z > Y) & !is.na(Z), "B", 
                ifelse(Z > Y & Y > X & !is.na(Z) & !is.na(X), "A", value)))
```